# AJAX error, Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal

I got an AJAX error while running Drupal 7.

"An AJAX error occured.
HTTP result code: 500
Debugging information follows:
Path: system/AJAX
StatusText: error
Response text:"

There is no response text. I have looked everywhere and tried a couple of things, but nothing works. Anyone have an idea on how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your [watchdog table](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/watchdog), if nothing there check the [php error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log).

Also use Firebug's console to check what is returned after the ajax request for any clues.

Can also try disabling third party modules one at a time to find out what is causing the error.